# How to check types between a dynamically loaded Assembly and a referenced Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Simply put, what I am doing is effectively making a "Shape package" with some valuable framework features for some other framework implementor.  I package up the Shape package into a class library and move on to writing a test implementation.  I load the Shape package .dll dynamically and reflect the types out of the assembly.  I can create objects, data bind to DataGridViews and whatever else I like - but I cannot pass a simple check like

```
if (squareObject is Shape)
or
if (Square.IsSubclassOf(Shape))
```

So as an example - 
If I have a class library with one class:

```
namespace Shapes
{
    public class Shape
    {
        public string UsefulShapeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I create an implementation library with one class (references Shapes library):

```
namespace MyShapes
{
    public class UselessShape : Shapes.Shape
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally, I create a third project that references the Shapes library and dynamically loads an implementation library, such as MyShapes:

```
using Shapes;
public class ShapeChecker
{
    ... (Constructor, some means to load and reflect the types from UselessShapes.dll, omitted for brevity and clarity)
    public void Report(Type typeToCheck)
    {
        if (typeToCheck.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Shapes.Shape)))
            Console.WriteLine("Rejoice, for " + typeToCheck.ToString() + " is a Shape!");
    }
}
```

I never get to "Rejoice."  I have also used Activator.CreateInstance and checked on the returned objects as well.  Activator gives me a UselessShape object, but the type check fails.

How can I check for implementations of certain known types (like Shape) in a dynamically loaded Assembly such that I don't need ShapeChecker to know anything special about the MyShapes package?

Comment: What is `Shape` in the `ShapeChecker`? And what is `typeToCheck`? (A short but *complete* example would really help here.)

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I mistyped System.Type's IsInstanceOfType method in my original example.  I've updated with more correctness and clarity.  Thanks!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think the problem is just that you're using the wrong method.

Currently you're asking whether the *type* of `Shape` is an instance of `Shape`... and it's not.

I suspect you want [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
if (typeof(Shapes.Shape).IsAssignableFrom(typeToCheck))
```

Note that I've reverse the target/argument here. I *think* I've got it the right way round, but I *always* have to check...

Comment: This also doesn't work.  I've tried it both ways and traced the debugger carefully.  The UselessShape type that is passed in is a RuntimeType which has the appropriately named Shape BaseType attribute - IsAssignableFrom is always false, and an explicit typecast throws an exception.

Comment: @Kenny: Well, this is definitely the method you want to get to work. I would check the BaseType carefully - in particular, check `typeToCheck.BaseType == typeof(Shape)`. I suspect you'll find it's not, which would mean the same type is being loaded from two different assemblies.

Comment: Thank you kindly, Mr. Skeet.  As it happens I was loading the test dll from an obviously incorrect location, resulting in even a recursive test of typeToCheck.BaseType failing.  PBKAC, as is often true.